# Python regex search giving none when it should match

Tags: python, regex

So I have...

```
regex = re.compile('\d{4,}:\s##(.*)##')
regex_search = regex.search(line.mesg)

        # This code is abbreviated. I go on to do things with
        # "result" in the try block but rather than junk up this 
        # post, here's the gist:
        try:
             result = regex_search.group(1)
        except AttributeError:
            print regex_search
```

Sample 'line.mesg' input (4 separate instances of line.mesg):

```
##Loading task.## 
##BEEP (375,2)##
##Aisle One One Seven##;pp
##Good night.##
```

Now, according to the testing at [pythex.org (click to see)](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5Cd%7B4%2C%7D%3A%5Cs%23%23%28.%2a%29%23%23&test_string=%285%2F12%2F14%2010%3A22%3A36%20AM%20EDT%29%2034438%3A%20%23%23Loading%20task.%23%23%0A%0A%285%2F12%2F14%2010%3A22%3A52%20AM%20EDT%29%203094962%3A%20%23%23BEEP%20%28375%2C2%29%23%23%0A%0A%285%2F12%2F14%2010%3A22%3A52%20AM%20EDT%29%203095975%3A%20%23%23Aisle%20One%20One%20Seven%23%23%3Bpp%0A%0A%285%2F12%2F14%2010%3A40%3A07%20AM%20EDT%29%204132712%3A%20%23%23Good%20night.%23%23&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0), I should be getting results from this. Yet every time I run through that code, it gets an exception, and `print regex_search` prints 'None'.

I'm not really sure what's wrong here, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I'm a moron - what I was testing with and what I was actually putting in weren't the same thing. The above regex does work for what I originally had for input (and what is found at the above pythex link) but what I was actually throwing into regex.search was what is currently above in the second code block.

TL;DR: unsurprisingly, when you rely on digits to match your regex, and then those digits aren't there, the regex doesn't match.

Comment: trying this exact code, after fixing teh indent error at teh `try` section it works fine?

Comment: It runs, sure, but it isn't properly matching the regex according to my testing.

Comment: I would suggest using a non-greedy operator: `(.*?)` instead of `(.*)` or `+?` if there is always something between the `##`, to avoid that `.*` matches the ending `##`

Comment: Error non reproducible without the try blocks: http://repl.it/Uj5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah i see the issue, if you are not tied to using `search` you can utilise [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) like in the example below.

```
import re
line = '''(5/12/14 10:22:36 AM EDT) 34438: ##Loading task.## 
(5/12/14 10:22:52 AM EDT) 3094962: ##BEEP (375,2)##
(5/12/14 10:22:52 AM EDT) 3095975: ##Aisle One One Seven##;pp
(5/12/14 10:40:07 AM EDT) 4132712: ##Good night.##'''

regex = re.compile('\d{4,}:\s##(.*)##+')
regex_search = regex.findall(line)

try:
   for result in regex_search.groups():
      print result
except AttributeError:
   print regex_search
```

which returns

```
['Loading task.', 'BEEP (375,2)', 'Aisle One One Seven', 'Good night.']
```

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be incorrect:

1. The result should be printed in the try block.
2. There is an extra ":" in the except line.

I don't know the exact input format of your line.mesg, so it is possible something is wrong there. But the following code works:

```
import re

line = '''\
(5/12/14 10:22:36 AM EDT) 34438: ##Loading task.##
(5/12/14 10:22:52 AM EDT) 3094962: ##BEEP (375,2)##
(5/12/14 10:22:52 AM EDT) 3095975: ##Aisle One One Seven##;pp
(5/12/14 10:40:07 AM EDT) 4132712: ##Good night.##
'''

regex = re.compile('\d{4,}:\s##(.*)##')
for line_msg in line.split('\n'):
    regex_search = regex.search(line_msg)

    try:
        result = regex_search.group(1)
        print result       # result should be printed here
    except AttributeError: # remove the ":" after "except"
        print regex_search
```